# Forcing rear camera to work as front camera in rooted device

Tags: android, camera, adb, root, su

I've been trying to force Android to use rear camera both as rear and front camera. This tweak should affect the whole system, so when any app tries to launch front camera, it will receive input from rear camera instead.

After some search I found [the following method in XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-camera-swap-on-rooted-tf101.1699299/post-80951735), it's meant to swap device cameras.

> 1. Remount the system partition as writable:
>
> `$ su -c mount -o rw,remount /system`
>
> 2. Edit /system/vendor/etc/camera/camera_config.xml and swap all
>
> `<Position>BACK</Position>`
>
> to
>
> `<Position>FRONT</Position>`
>
> and vice versa.
>
> 3. Reboot.

I managed do to it and it only messed up with my cameras orientation. I tried launching WhatsApp camera and it only recognized my front camera (couldn't switch to rear).

I can't find any official documentation on how Android manages device cameras.

I need some insights if it's possible do to this tweak, how could it be done and why the above method didn't work as intended.